# Loop in jquery based on razor loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a for each loop in my razor view (MVC4)

```
 @foreach (var fe in ViewBag.FeatureProducts)
  {

    <div class="product-details" style="display:none;">@Html.Raw(fe.Details)</div>
    <div class="product-qty-dt">   </div>

  }
```

in the each loop i have to extract the @html row content and display in to the div   'product-qty-dt'.

For that I write the following jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
       var data = $('.product-details p').map(function () {
           return $(this).text();
       }).get();           
       //product availability
       var availability = data[2].split(",");        
       $.each(availability, function (i) {
           $('.product-qty-dt').append( availability[i])
       });

   });
```

But this was only consider the last foreach raw. how can i call this jquery in each loop call.

For  example, In first loop,

```
  <div class="product-details" style="display:none;"><p>Lorem, Ispum</p><p>doler emit,fghjh</p><p>9gm</p></div>
  <div class="product-qty-dt"> 9gm  </div>
```

second loop

```
 <div class="product-details" style="display:none;"><p>Lorem, Ispum</p><p>doler emit,fghjh</p><p>5gm</p></div>
 <div class="product-qty-dt"> 5gm  </div>
```

Thirdloop

```
 <div class="product-details" style="display:none;"><p>Lorem, Ispum</p><p>doler emit,fghjh</p><p>3gm</p></div>
 <div class="product-qty-dt"> 3gm  </div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to have a view model with properties for the data you want to display (no javascript at all). In any case, an example of what `@Html.Raw(fe.Details)` generates would help.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sample of @Html.Raw(fe.Details) contesnt: <p>Lorem, Ispum</p><p>doler emit,fghjh</p><p>9gm</p>

Comment: Please edit the question (too difficult to read in comments especially if you dont format them), and can you indicate what the expected output will be - i.e. to be appended to `$('.product-qty-dt')`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Edited my question ..please helpme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will add the text of the last `<p>` in a `<div class="product-details">` element into the corresponding `<div class="product-qty-dt">` element

```
$('.product-details').each(function () {
  var t = $(this).children('p').last().text();
  $(this).next('.product-qty-dt').text(t);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Also the `data` array is still used just incase you would like to access other data portions stored in product-details.

```
$(".product-details").each(function()
    {
        var data = $(this).find('p').map(function () { return $(this).text() }).get();
        $(this).next('.product-qty-dt').text(data[2]);
    })
```